# Postgres function error

Tags: function, postgresql, csv

I'm creating a function in postgres and getting strange error. What am I doing wrong? I also would like to see your variants how to do it

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION export_csv(request TEXT, filename VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VOID AS 
$$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'COPY (' || request || ') TO "/home/r90t/work/study/etl/postgres_etl/export/' || filename || '" WITH CSV;';
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

REQUEST:

```
SELECT export_csv('SELECT * FROM orders', 'orders.csv')
```

ERROR:

```
psql:/tmp/vUp267V/dbext.sql:2: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""/home/r90t/work/study/etl/postgres_etl/export/orders.csv""
LINE 1: COPY (SELECT * FROM orders) TO "/home/r90t/work/study/etl/po...
                                   ^$
QUERY:  COPY (SELECT * FROM orders) TO "/home/r90t/work/study/etl/postgres_etl/export/orders.csv" WITH CSV;
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function export_csv(text,character varying) line 3 at EXECUTE statement
```

Comment: String literals need to be enclosed in single quotes, not double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh boy.....

First, because you COPY TO FILE, your function must run as superuser, and you are inlining an SQL query provided by the user into that file.  At least you must run the query as superuser and you haven't set SECURITY DEFINER on it.  But the whole point of your function is SQL injection and for very little gain.  I get that this is a bit for personal study but there is nothing to be gained by doing it in a way that would put a business's data at risk in the future.

In particular, I wonder what would happen if I do something like:

```
 SELECT export_csv('SELECT * FROM ORDERS TO STDOUT; DROP DATABASE critical_db; --', 'foo');
```

or

```
 SELECT export_csv('SELECT * FROM ORDERS', '../../../../../../../var/lib/pgsql/data/log/postgresql-Tue.log');
```

Really, really, really bad stuff are possible with your function.  Don't do it.  these are contained now but as soon as someone does the following, you are totally:

```
 ALTER FUNCTION export_csv SET SECURITY DEFINER;
```

A better approach would be to take a single argument that can be quoted and processed in place.  Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION export_csv(relation name, columns name[])
RETURNS VOID AS 
$$
DECLARE column_list text;
BEGIN
  SELECT array_to_string(cols, ', ') INTO column_list
    FROM (SELECT array_agg(quote_literal(col)) as cols
            FROM unnest(columns) col
         ) a;

  EXECUTE 'COPY (SELECT ' || column_list || ' FROM ' || quote_ident(relation) || ') 
           TO ' || quote_literal('/home/r90t/work/study/etl/postgres_etl/export/' || relation) || ' WITH CSV;';
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This would give you protection against sql injection, and if you need the date added on to the end, you can do that with something inside the quote_literal call.